# Firebase Ui auth version 3.2.2 xml errors

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to connect a firebaseUI auth but I keep getting an error with an unknown xml file

Here is my build gradle files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        resConfigs "auto"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}




dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


and here is the xml file which appears:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
    <style name="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 26+ -->
        <item name="colorError">?android:attr/colorError</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 26+ -->
        <item name="colorError">?android:attr/colorError</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.V26.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar" parent="Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:touchscreenBlocksFocus">true</item>
        <item name="android:keyboardNavigationCluster">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar" parent="Base.V26.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"/>
</resources>
```

Here are the errors which appear from this:

```
[:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
    Error:(252, 5) error: resource android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster not found.
Error:(252, 5) error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
Error:(252, 5) error: resource android:attr/font not found.
Error:(252, 5) error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
C:\and-nd-firebase-1.00-starting-point\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml
Error:(36) error: style attribute 'android:attr/autofillHints' not found.
Error:(7) resource android:attr/colorError not found.
Error:(11) resource android:attr/colorError not found.
Error:(15) style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
Error:(18) style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
Error:(24) style attribute 'android:attr/autofillHints' not found.
Error:(28) style attribute 'android:attr/autofillHints' not found.
Error:(32) style attribute 'android:attr/autofillHints' not found.
Error:(36) style attribute 'android:attr/autofillHints' not found.
C:\and-nd-firebase-1.00-starting-point\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Error:(250) resource android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster not found.
Error:(468) resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
Error:(468) resource android:attr/font not found.
```

details
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Failed to execute aapt
>       Information:BUILD FAILED in 8s
>       Information:29 errors
>       Information:0 warnings
>       Information:See complete output in console

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use version 27.0.2 of the Support libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```

And change:

```
compileSdkVersion 27  // was 24
```

You may also want to use the latest version of Glide:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
```